Avoid request creation if circuit is open and directly call fallback method
I am trying to implement a circuit breaker pattern. Now to populate my request there are closed to 5 DB calls that are made.
I want to avoid these calls if my circuit is in open state, in order to save some DB hits. Does resillency4j provide any handle that would tell me if my circuit is open or half open?
